# No route matches [GET] after post validation error Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, coffeescript

I'm dynamically updating my form fields with AJAX based on selections from other select fields.  Everything works fine on first entry.  Although, after submitting the form with validation errors and using render 'new' I'm receiving a routing error.  I added the route for update_players above resources (see below).  I believe there's something wrong with my routes.

This was my reference: https://kernelgarden.wordpress.com/2014/02/26/dynamic-select-boxes-in-rails-4/

**config/routes.rb:**

```
...
    get 'games/update_players', as: 'update_players'
    resources :games
...
```

**raked routes:**

```
...
  update_players GET    /games/update_players(.:format) games#update_players
           games GET    /games(.:format)                games#index
                 POST   /games(.:format)                games#create
        new_game GET    /games/new(.:format)            games#new
       edit_game GET    /games/:id/edit(.:format)       games#edit
            game GET    /games/:id(.:format)            games#show
                 PATCH  /games/:id(.:format)            games#update
                 PUT    /games/:id(.:format)            games#update
                 DELETE /games/:id(.:format)            games#destroy
...
```

**games_controller.rb**

```
  def show
    @game = Game.find(params[:id])
  end  

  def new
    @users = User.all
    @game = Game.new
  end

  def create
    @game = Game.new(game_params)
    if @game.save
      flash[:success] = 'Game Saved!'
      redirect_to current_user
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = 'Game did not save'
      @users = User.all
      render 'new'
    end
  end
...
  def update_players
    @users = Group.find(params[:group_id]).users
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

**assets/javascripts/games.coffee:**

```
update_players = ->
  $.ajax 'update_players',
    type: 'GET'
    dataType: 'script'
    data: {
      group_id: $("#groups-select option:selected").val()
    }
    error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
      console.log("AJAX Error: #{textStatus}")
    success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
      console.log("Dynamic player select OK!")

$(document).on 'ready page:load', update_players
$(document).on 'change', '#groups-select', update_players
```

**views/games/update_players.js.coffee:**

```
$("#players-select").empty()
  .append("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "players_in_group_list")) %>")
```

**After rendering 'new' on create this is the error I receive:**

```
Started GET "/update_players?group_id=1&_=1458493122921" for ::1 at 2016-03-20 10:58:43 -0600

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/update_players"):
```

## **SOLUTION POSTED BELOW**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## **SOLUTION:**

I needed to use an absolute path for the ajax url.  Because I was using a relative path `'update_players'` in my ajax url, rails was prepending `games/` on the new action but not on the create action.  The routes stayed the same.

**Updated assets/javascripts/games.coffee:**

```
update_players = ->
  $.ajax '/games/update_players',
    type: 'GET'
    dataType: 'script'
    data: {
      group_id: $("#groups-select option:selected").val()
    }
    error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
      console.log("AJAX Error: #{textStatus}")
    success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
      console.log("Dynamic player select OK!")

$(document).on 'ready page:load', update_players
$(document).on 'change', '#groups-select', update_players
```

Thank you [Зелёный](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2057388/%d0%97%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%91%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9) for sending me down the right path

Answer (score 2):

According to your routes, the url in `ajax` should be:

```
update_players = ->
  $.ajax 'games/update_players',
  type: 'GET'
    dataType: 'script'
    data: {
      group_id: $("#groups-select option:selected").val()
    }
    error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
      console.log("AJAX Error: #{textStatus}")
    success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
      console.log("Dynamic player select OK!")

$(document).on 'ready page:load', update_players
$(document).on 'change', '#groups-select', update_players
```

Or change your routes:

```
get 'update_players', to: 'games#update_players' as: 'update_players'
```

ajax:

```
 update_players = ->
      $.ajax 'update_players',      
     type: 'GET'
    dataType: 'script'
    data: {
      group_id: $("#groups-select option:selected").val()
    }
    error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
      console.log("AJAX Error: #{textStatus}")
    success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
      console.log("Dynamic player select OK!")

$(document).on 'ready page:load', update_players
$(document).on 'change', '#groups-select', update_players
```

Also fix the quotes:

```
$("#players-select").empty().append("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'players_in_group_list')) %>")
```

Comment: This gives me a better understanding, although doesn't quite fix the problem.  Because the $.ajax call happens in games.coffee it prepends games/ to the route on first entry.  Once again, on error (after rendering 'new') it no longer prepends and leaves me with the missing route '/update_players'.  If I add 'games/' to the ajax call, it work after the error but not on first entry.  Changing the route to `get 'update_players', as 'update_players'` gives me the routing error: `Missing :controller key on routes definition`.  Also, thanks for catching the quote problem!

Comment: use `get 'update_players', to: 'games#update_players' as: 'update_players'` to fix `Missing :controller key on routes definition`

Comment: That fixes `Missing:controller key on routes def` and allows the route to work after the form submits but does not work on first entry with this error: `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Game with 'id'=update_players): app/controllers/games_controller.rb:10:in `show'`... Strange; after rendering 'new' it attempts to process `GamesController#show as JS`... Updated the games_controller.rb above to display the show def.